# Extract String out of an RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I have a DataFrame in which the rows has two doubles. I want to generate a formatted String that represents the DataFrame as a JSON list. Here is my code:

```
df.rdd.take(5)
val values = df.rdd.map{ case Row(x :Double ,y: Double) => (x,y,50) }
```

`take(5)` from the RDD looks like this:

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([41.64068433800631,37.689287325884315], [37.01941012184662,30.390807326639077], [34.02364443854447,40.55991398223156], [41.52505975127479,42.02651332703204], [39.33233947587333,33.62091706778894])
```

I want to have a String that looks like this:

```
"[[41.64068433800631,37.689287325884315, 50], [37.01941012184662,30.390807326639077, 50], [34.02364443854447,40.55991398223156, 50], [41.52505975127479,42.02651332703204, 50], [39.33233947587333,33.62091706778894, 50]]
```

I have tried a sequential approach to generate string but I get a weird error:

```
val valuesCol = values.collect()

var a = "["

for( a <- 1 to valuesCol.length){
    a = a + "[" + valuesCol(1)._1+ "," + valuesCol(1)._2 + "," + valuesCol(1)._3 + "]"
}
a =  a + "]"

println(a)
```

The error is:

```
error: reassignment to val
```

As you can see `a` is a `var`. I don't get what is the problem. Any ways to fix this error or any other approach will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily using this.

```
val data = Array((1,2,1),(1,2,11),(23,8,1))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
val res ="["+  rdd.map{ case(x,y,z) => "["+ x + "," + y + "," + z + "]" }.collect.mkString(",") + "]"
```

Output:

```
res: String = [[1,2,1],[1,2,11],[23,8,1]]
```